# Docker daemon running under SSL contacted using cURL

Tags: ssl, docker

I have setup docker in non-ssl mode by editing `/etc/default/docker` and setting `DOCKER_OPTS="-H=0.0.0.0:2375"`.

Now when I start docker and connect to it using curl `curl -sv http://10.24.16.17:2375/v1.22/containers/json`, I get some response.

When I secure the docker using certificates (`ca.pem`, `server-key.pem`, `server-cert.pem`) and editing `/etc/default/docker`

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--tlsverify --tlscacert=/home/ubuntu/certs/ca.pem --tlscert=/home/ubuntu/certs/server-cert.pem --tlskey=/home/ubuntu/certs/server-key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376"
```

I am not able to connect service using curl:

`curl -sv https://10.24.16.17:2376/v1.22/containers/json`

I get the following output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.24.16.17...
* Connected to 10.24.16.17 (10.24.16.17) port 2376 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

I am able to run `docker ps -a` command using CLI though, only cURL to hit the API endpoint does not work.

When I try `curl -sv --cacert /home/ubuntu/certs/ca.pem https://10.24.16.17:2376/v1.22/containers/json`, I get:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.24.16.17...
* Connected to 10.24.16.17 (10.24.16.17) port 2376 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/ubuntu/certs/ca.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

I read somewhere that the above error may be due to corrupt `ca.pem` file, but that may not be the case as the command `docker ps -a` was able to connect to docker host using the same `ca.pem` file.

Comment: ive known a few issues like this where running apt-get -y update inside the container fixes the issue - worth a shot